# Can an $R$-module have bases of different cardinality?

Tags: modules, examples-counterexamples

I am not so very familiar with the mathematics of *modules over rings*. I heard of them as a generalization of vector spaces with a ring instead of a field. I also heard of them as providing many pathological examples when thinking in the familiar term of vector spaces (there was an MO thread discussing examples, but I cannot find it). E.g. I learned that an $R$-module (over some ring $R$) does not necessarily have a *basis*, even though it has independent and generating sets. My immediate next question then was:

> **Question**: Can an $R$-module have *bases* of different cardinality?

I am especially interested in different finite cardinalities. Can you give me an example of such a module? Or is it that the dimension of an $R$-module (if at all) can be still defined uniquely?

Comment: There are several questions linked to the duplicate that explain examples where $R\cong R^2$ as $R$ modules. For such a ring, $R^n\cong R^m$ for every positive integers $n,m$. Here is a [second link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1265300/29335). You should just search for "invariant basis number".

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with a non-commutative ring $R$ that the left
$R$-modules $R^m$ and $R^n$ to be non-isomorphic for some finite $m\ne n$.

An example of such a ring is the endomorphism ring of an infinite-dimensional vector space over a field.

A ring such that $R^m\cong R^n$ entails $m=n$ is said to have
[Invariant Basis Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number).