# Injectivity/surjectivity of A-linear maps, and the dimension of free modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with one, and $A^n, A^m$ be free modules over $A$. Let $\varphi:A^m\rightarrow A^n$. I want to show that if $\varphi$ is injective, then $m\leq n$. Similarly, if $\varphi$ is surjective, then $m\geq n$.

My attempt:
Let $\varphi:A^m \rightarrow A^n$ be $A$-linear. Let $x_1,...,x_m$ and $y_1,...,y_n$ be bases of $A^n$ and $A^m$, respectively. By the universal property of free modules, $\varphi$ is induced by a function $\tilde{\varphi}:\{x_1,...,x_m\}\rightarrow \{y_1,...,y_m\}$. We now know that there exists an injective map between two sets $X$ and $Y$ if and only if $\mid X\mid \leq \mid Y \mid$. A similar argument delivers the second statement.

Is my solution correct? If not, where does it fail?

Comment: You need to assume that $A$ is commutative (or that $A$ has the "invariant basis number'" property if you want the weakest possible condition), otherwise the statement fails to hold

Comment: For examples where the statement fails to hold, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1265300/81360)

Comment: Oh, you're right. In Atiyah-McDonald "ring" means "commutative ring with one". I will fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have stated in the comments, this statement fails to hold without further assumptions on $A$.  Since your proof doesn't use these assumptions, it must be wrong somewhere.

Concretely the problem with your proof is the following: the universal property allows us to say that $\varphi : A^m \to A^n$ is induced by a function $\tilde \varphi:\{x_1,\dots,x_m\} \to A^n$.  However, we cannot state a priori that the target of $\tilde \varphi$ is some fixed basis $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ of $A^n$.

Comment: So, one would have to say that $\tilde{\varphi}$ is onto some finite subset  $\{\varphi(x_1),...,\varphi(x_m)\}\subset A^n$, then show that any subset of order $\geq n$ is linearly independent?

Comment: First of all, your comment is wrong by any interpretation: any subset of order $> n$ would be linearly **dependent**, and we can certainly construct linearly dependent subsets that are as small as you like. What you should say is that if $\varphi$ is injective, then $\{\varphi(x_1),...,\varphi(x_m)\}\subset A^n$ must be linearly independent, which means that the set (of $m$ elements) contains at most $n$ elements.

Comment: again made a couple of typos. Thanks for the clarification!